# Conflict between 2 js files

Tags: magento2

I have a conflict between 2 js files. I have 2 modules Ced_Storepickup & Bss_Onestepcheckout & both modules are using

`js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js`

file.

What is the proper way to set both files functionality?